# Equivalent Gaussian measures

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gaussian

Let $\mu$ be a gaussian measure with eigenpair $\{e_k,2^{-k}\}$ and $\nu$ with eigenpair $\{ Te_k,2^{-k}\}$. Here, T is the unitary operator given by $Tx = x - 2\left\langle x,v \right\rangle v$. Let $v = \sum g(i)e_i$. Now, they are absolutely continuous with respect to each other if $I - G^{-1/2}G'G^{-1/2}$ is trace class where G and G' are covariance operators of $\mu$ and $\nu$ respectively(according to Kuo). We can see that it happens for any value of v. But, if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are absolutely continuous wrt each other, they should have the same cameron martin space.In particular, $Te_k$ should belong to the cameron martin space of $\mu$ for all k. That is clearly not true for all values of v.
What is going wrong here? Also, Kuo does state other conditions but they are satisfied if $I - G^{-1/2}G'G^{-1/2}$ is trace class.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Hilbert-Schmidt" instead of "trace class"? Anyway, I believe that for most $v$ your $I - G^{-1/2} G^\prime G^{-1/2}$ is not even bounded.

Comment: Trace class implies Hilbert Schmidt.To see that it is actually trace class - $\textit{I} - G^{-1/2}G'G^{-1/2} = \textit{I} - G^{-1/2}TGTG^{-1/2} = A + A^t - AA^t$. Here $A = 2G^{-1/2}SG^{1/2}$ and $S(x) = \left\langle x,v\right\rangle v$. So, if A is trace class, we are done.$\sum_i \left\langle Ae_i,e_i\right\rangle = \sum_i \left\langle 2\lambda_iG^{-1/2}\left\langle e_i,v\right\rangle v,e_i\right\rangle = \sum_i \left\langle 2\lambda_ig(i)\sum_j \frac{g(j)}{\lambda_j}e_j,e_i\right\rangle = 2 \sum_i g(i)^2 = 2 $

Comment: Yeah, ok. Seem to have got it. The definition of trace I was using applies only to positive definite operators.